# Printing strings on screen

Tags: android

I have a multiple Strings in held  in variables. They are being sent from a text box from another activity. I want to print each string separately but do not know how to do so. The method I am using to get the string is:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData)
{
    String addedNote = resultData.getStringExtra("note");


}
```

What do I add underneath to print the addedNote?

Thank You

Comment: What do you mean with print? Set the text in a TextView and it will be shown

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question might be clearer if you showed a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

As IgorB said, you can use a TextView to display the text. Otherwise, if you wish to print temporarily and not add any views to the display, just make a `Toast`.

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), resultData.getStringExtra("note"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate them in TextView like this :

```
String text = "line1\n line2\n line3";
textView.setText(text);
```